# How to remove "Ubuntu Software" list entry having "no packages to remove"?

Tags: 20.04, software-center, uninstall

I'm running Ubunutu 20.4 LTS and tried to install an application ("FlightGear" - a flight simulator). After a while nothing happened and according to the comments the installation may be broken. So I tried to stop the installation. But now the application ("FlightGear") is listed in "Ubuntu Software" at the "Installed" tab. When clicking "uninstall" an error message pops up: "no packages to remove". I tried to reopen the application "Ubuntu Software", but the broken entry still exists. Regarding to "apt list --installed" there's no flightgear package installed.

[Screenshot: Error message in "Ubuntu Software"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re4Fy.png)

How to get rid of it? (Advanced question: Why does the application "Ubuntu Software" doesn't ignore a "no packages to remove" error and just removes the list-entry?)

Comment: Include the commands you are using and the whole output of each command. A narrative description in your own words does not really give us any actionable info.

Comment: For verbose output, please run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in a terminal. Post the complete output of each command in your question. Use copy/paste and [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for formatting. Please do not upload screenshots of your terminal

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score -1):

One way is to try to remove it with apt-get:

[command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rUeH.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).